# Networkx weighted graph hover

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx, bokeh

I've been using the following code to create a weighted Networkx graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge("a", "b", weight=0.6)
G.add_edge("a", "c", weight=0.2)
G.add_edge("c", "d", weight=0.1)
G.add_edge("c", "e", weight=0.7)
G.add_edge("c", "f", weight=0.9)
G.add_edge("a", "d", weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d["weight"] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d["weight"] <= 0.5]

pos = nx.circular_layout(G, scale=5000)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge, width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G, pos, edgelist=esmall, width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color="b", style="dashed"
)

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family="sans-serif")

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the output:]

I wanted to also add hover capabilities between relationships to my plot. I wanted to use [this](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html#interaction-policies) tool from Bokeh, but I wasn't sure how to incorporate it into my code, any ideas on how I could incorporate the hover feature? Thank you very much.